# How can I use Spring Batch with OSGI

Tags: java, osgi, spring-batch

I want to use Spring batch with osgi to run a job daily.
here what i did:

```
@Component
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {


private JobBuilderFactory jobs;
public JobBuilderFactory getJobs() {
    return jobs;
}

public void setJobs(JobBuilderFactory jobs) {
    this.jobs = jobs;
}


private StepBuilderFactory steps;

private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository; //spring data repository

public EmployeeRepository getEmployeeRepository() {
    return employeeRepository;
}

@Reference
public void setEmployeeRepository(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
    employeeRepository= employeeRepository;
}





public Step syncEmployeesStep() throws Exception{
    RepositoryItemWriter writer = new RepositoryItemWriter();
    writer.setRepository(employeeRepository);
    writer.setMethodName("save");
    return steps.get("syncEmployeesStep")
            .<Employee, Employee> chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
}


public Job importEmpJob()throws Exception {
    return jobs.get("importEmpJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(syncEmployeesStep())
            .next(syncEmployeesStep())
            .build();
}


public ItemReader<Employee> reader() throws Exception {
    String jpqlQuery = "select a from Employee a";
        ServerEMF entityManager = new ServerEMF();
        JpaPagingItemReader<Employee> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<Tariff>();
        reader.setQueryString(jpqlQuery);
        reader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory());
        reader.setPageSize(3);
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
        reader.setSaveState(true);

        return reader;
}
}
```

here I want to run this job to sync between two databases,My problem is how to run this job inside osgi.

```
@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class JobRunner {

 private JobLauncher jobLauncher;  
 private Job job ; 
 private BatchConfiguration batchConfig;
//private  JobBuilderFactory jobs;
//private JobRepository jobrepo;



final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);

BundleContext ctx;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
ServiceTracker servicetracker;



@Activate
public void start(BundleContext context) {
    batchConfig = new BatchConfiguration();
    //jobs = new JobBuilderFactory(jobRepository)
    try {
    job = batchConfig.importEmpJob(); //job is null because i don't know how to use it
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ctx = context;

    servicetracker= new ServiceTracker(ctx, BatchConfiguration.class, null);
    servicetracker.open();

    new Thread() {
        public void run() { findAndRunJob(); }
    }.start();
}



@Deactivate
public void stop() {
    configAdminTracker.close();

}


 @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
protected void findAndRunJob() {

     logger.info("job created.");
      try {  
           String dateParam = new Date().toString();  
           JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("date", dateParam).toJobParameters();  
           System.out.println(dateParam);  
           JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, param);  
           System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());  
             } catch (Exception e) {  
              //e.printStackTrace();  
             }  


}
```

for sure,I got a java.lang.NullPointerException because the job is null.
could anyone help me with that?

after updates

```
@Component
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public class BatchConfiguration {




  private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository; //spring data repository

   public EmployeeRepository getEmployeeRepository() {
    return employeeRepository;
  }

    @Reference
   public void setEmployeeRepository(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
    employeeRepository= employeeRepository;
     }





       public Step syncEmployeesStep() throws Exception{
    RepositoryItemWriter writer = new RepositoryItemWriter();
    writer.setRepository(employeeRepository);
    writer.setMethodName("save");
    return steps.get("syncEmployeesStep")
            .<Employee, Employee> chunk(10)
            .reader(reader())
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
}


public Job importEmpJob(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager)throws Exception  {
   JobBuilderFactory jobs= new JobBuilderFactory(jobRepository);
     StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory = new StepBuilderFactory(jobRepository, transactionManager);
    return jobs.get("importEmpJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(syncEmployeesStep())
            .next(syncEmployeesStep())
            .build();
}


public ItemReader<Employee> reader() throws Exception {
    String jpqlQuery = "select a from Employee a";
        ServerEMF entityManager = new ServerEMF();
        JpaPagingItemReader<Employee> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<Tariff>();
        reader.setQueryString(jpqlQuery);
        reader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory());
        reader.setPageSize(3);
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
        reader.setSaveState(true);

        return reader;
}
}
```

job runner class

```
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
        private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
        private JobRepository jobRepository;

        Job importEmpJob;

        private BatchConfiguration batchConfig;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Activate
    public void start(BundleContext context) {

            try {
    batchConfig = new BatchConfiguration();

              this.transactionManager = new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
                MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean repositorybean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
                repositorybean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
                this.jobRepository = repositorybean.getJobRepository(); //error after executing this statement
                // setup job launcher
                SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
                simpleJobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());
                simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);

                this.jobLauncher = simpleJobLauncher;
        //System.out.println(job);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ctx = context;

        configAdminTracker = new ServiceTracker(ctx, BatchConfiguration.class.getName(), null);
        configAdminTracker.open();

        new Thread() {
            public void run() { findAndRunJob(); }
        }.start();
    }



    @Deactivate
    public void stop() {
        configAdminTracker.close();

    }
    protected void findAndRunJob() {

         logger.info("job created.");
          try {  

               String dateParam = new Date().toString();  

                 // creating the job
                Job job = batchConfig.importEmpJob(jobRepository, transactionManager);

                // running the job
                JobExecution execution = this.jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());

               System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());  
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                  //e.printStackTrace();  
                 }


    }
```

what i getting is "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository is not visible from class loader" after running .could anyone help me with that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Short**

If you're just trying to kick off a something simple and don't need all the Spring Batch goodness I would look into the Apache Sling Commons Scheduler which has a simple job processor on top of Quartz for scheduling[1].

**In General**

There are a couple of considerations here depending on what you are trying to do.  Are you deploying the Spring Batch Jars to the OSGi container with the assumption that the code that is written for the jobs (steps, tasks, etc) will live in separate bundles?  OSGi's purpose is to develop modular code so my answer is assuming that this is your end goal.  The folks at Pivotal have dropped requiring support for OSGi on their artifacts so to make it work you'll need to determine what you need to export from the Batch jar files.  This can be done with BND. I would recommend checking out the new BND Maven plugin [2].  I would configure the Export-Package to export the interfaces you need to write the jobs so that you can write the jobs in separate modular bundles.  Then I would probably embed the spring batch jars in a bundle and write a small wrapper around the JobLauncher.  This should contain all the actual batch code to a single classloader so that you don't have to worry about OSGi trying to pull in classes dynamically.  The downside is that this will prevent you from using many of the batch annotations outside of the spring batch bundle you created but will provide the modularity that you'd be looking for by implementing this type of solution with OSGi.

[1] https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/apache-sling-eventing-and-job-handling.html

[2] http://njbartlett.name/2015/03/27/announcing-bnd-maven-plugin.html

Comment: thanks for your help and reply.I already using bndtools and i have the BatchConfiguration class in a separate bundle.but after initializing the job,i still can't get it to work.could you please give me an example?

Comment: There aren't examples of using batch in a general sense the way you're looking to do it available.  If you want to use apache camel there are some examples online. http://camel.apache.org/springbatch.html

Comment: This is already batch bundle that i use  that export all the interfaces i need [link]http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-batch-core)

Comment: Yeah the servicemix project still does attempt to provide the OSGi bundles for many popular spring projects but the community is not as large as camel if you are looking for examples

Comment: Also the service mix JAR only includes spring batch not all the dependencies.  It's expected that you have all of those active in the OSGi container before your bundle will spin up.

Comment: If the interface is not visible from the classloader that means that the bundle is not importing it.  What does your pom.xml look like?

Comment: Thanks Bob for your help.I tried  Apache Sling Commons Scheduler and it did fit my requirements.